# Seg Fault when calling enQueue function in a Queue

Tags: c, stack, queue

There is a segmentation fault in my enQueue function and I don't understand why it is present (other than the fact the I am accessing memory that I am not allowed to access).

My enQueue function is intended to insert a node at the head of the linked list. My deQueue function is intended to traverse the linked list and delete the tail of the list.

Here are associated structs:

```
typedef struct studstruct{
  int age;
  struct studstruct *nextPtr;
}Student;

typedef struct linkedlist{
  Student *head, *tail;
}StudentList;
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main(void){
  StudentList *myQueue=initQueue();
  int tracker;

  tracker=enQueue(myQueue, 4);
  printf("Enqueue returned: %d\n", tracker);
  tracker=enQueue(myQueue, 3);
  printf("Enqueue returned: %d\n", tracker);
  tracker=enQueue(myQueue, 2);
  printf("Enqueue returned: %d\n", tracker);
  tracker=enQueue(myQueue, 1);
  printf("Enqueue returned: %d\n", tracker);

  printf("After enqueue:\n");
  printList(myQueue);

  (myQueue->head)=deQueue(myQueue);

  printf("After dequeue:\n");
  printList(myQueue);

  freeList(myQueue);
}
```

Here is my enQueue function:

```
int enQueue(StudentList *node,int data){
  Student *newNode;
  newNode = createStudentNode(data);
  newNode->nextPtr=node->head;

  if(node->head==newNode->nextPtr){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Here is my deQueue function:

```
Student* deQueue(StudentList *node){
  Student *temp=node->head;
  Student *temp2;

  while(temp->nextPtr!=NULL){
    temp2=temp;
    temp=temp->nextPtr;
  }
  free(temp2->nextPtr);
  temp2->nextPtr=NULL;

  return node->head;
}
```

Here is my createNode function which dynamically allocates memory to my node:

```
Student *createStudentNode(int data){
  Student *node;
  node = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
  if(node){
    node->nextPtr=NULL;
    node->age=data;
  }
  return node;
}
```

Comment: In `enQueue()` the `node` is not a node, but is a pointer to the list "base", so the name is a little obscure: but in any case: should you be setting `node->head` and/or `node->tail` ?  BTW, is `enQueue()` intended to append or prepend ?  And `deQueue()` doesn't seem to consider the possibility that `node->head` may be `NULL`, but also perhaps should be setting `node->head` and/or `node->tail` ?

Comment: using a debugger and looking at the faulting line instantly solves questions like these, I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to change the new head of the StudentList if you pre-append or tail if you post-append

```
int enQueue(StudentList *node,int data){
  Student *newNode;
  newNode = createStudentNode(data);
  newNode->nextPtr = node->head;
  node->head = newNode;

  if(node->head==newNode->nextPtr){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return -1;
  }
}
```